# Regex for email localpart

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using html pattern for email localpart for validation before @

Using the below regex

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_!#$%&'*+/=?`{|}~^-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9_!#$%&'*+/=?`{|}~^-]+)*$
```

Now i know that local part should be 64 characters. Kindly help where to put the length so that combine length of this local part should be less than 64 characters

Comment: Use match and string .length

Comment: Can you give me example

Comment: ```"abcabc".match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_!#$%&'*+/=?`{|}~^-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9_!#$%&'*+/=?`{|}~^-]+)*$/)[0].length < 64```

Comment: After the first `^`, add `(?=[^@]{1,64}@)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't want to check domain only before domain as i am selecting domain from dropdown

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your answer needs little bit change and the below works for me
^(?=[^@]{1,64}$)